# I only have header file from framework in iOS, but need to change property

Tags: ios, frameworks, header, delegates, categories

Here is the things.

I use a framework which contains only header files.

The framework use SOMEWebView which is a subclass of UIWebView.

I need to set this SOMEWebViews property "allowsInlineMediaPlayback" to "YES".

That webView is used by SOMEViewController's UIWebViewDelegate.

How can I make this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a category on SOMEWebView that has the following method declaration:

```
+ (BOOL)allowsInlineMediaPlayback
{
    return YES;
}
```

EDIT:

N.B. Only do this when you control the code you're overriding. Doing this without knowing what you're doing can cause undesirable behaviour (especially when overriding Apple framework classes using this method). Since you're not in control of the code, I'd suggest you also check out "method swizzling" or see if you can simply subclass the SOMEWebView in question.

Comment: it is a **bad** advice... overriding a instance method in a category causes undefined behaviour in runtime.

Comment: The alternatives are subclassing the view controller or swizzling the method.

Comment: subclassing is the _only_ way how you have to override any method in ObjC. (of course not, on advanced-level in runtime you can exchange the instance methods' bodies in a simple category, but your answer is definitely not doing such a thing – therefore it is incorrect).

Comment: I wasn't disagreeing with you. This will work, but it is discouraged by Apple. YMMV.

Comment: I understand you, but why would you recommended such an idea even if you already know that the runtime behaviour is _undefined_? what is the point in giving 'wrong' answer?

Comment: It's not undefined. It will call the method always. It's only undefined if you have two categories implementing the same method.

Comment: interesting notion... but FYI: _If the name of a method declared in a category is the same as a method in the original class, or a method in another category on the same class (or even a superclass), the behavior is **undefined** as to which method implementation is used at runtime._ source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html, I guess Apple has a very strong opinion about how undefined is. you are welcome.

Comment: Yeah, it's 'undefined' because they want to discourage its use. In reality, it will always call the category. But yes, probably shouldn't use this as a solution.

Comment: your interpretation is really funny. in reality it is _undefined_, because the _undefined_ means the actual thing is _undefined_. if they want to discourage you, they will say _something else recommended to use instead_... have you ever understood their documentation's language...? please, link me where the Apple says about this thing _it is undefined, but in runtime the category will be called always_...

Comment: @holex, continue reading your linked documentation. *This is less likely to be an issue if you’re using categories with your own classes, but can cause problems when using categories to add methods to standard Cocoa classes.* Apple is basically stating, that this is a safe practice when its your own code. You run into issues when using things such as class clusters or unknowningly overriding library behaviour which an internal implementation relies on. Only use a category to override a method if you know what you're doing. This works and is correct, however, I'll add a caveat to my answer.

Comment: The statement _"This is less likely to be an issue (...)"_ is far away to be equal to _safe practice on your own code_. that statement is only about the Apple does not care about how you ruin your own code in runtime, but you should not create an undefined situation in their framework.